# Is there a way to predict multiple columns of NA values in a dataset using R?

Tags: r, predictive-models

I have a data set that has 9 different variables, but 3 of the variables aren't complete. I'd like to find a way to use a prediction model to fill in those variables, but was wondering if there was a way to do it for all 3 at once, rather than creating 3 different regressions, then 20 different datasets for each line of data and then plugging it into the Predict() function. I feel like I'm doing a ton of unnecessary work but haven't found anything online for how to do what I'm looking for. I know how to do it in Stata, but would much rather use R for my work.

Comment: It might help if you explain what method you are using in Stata (not the details of the code, just the underlying machinery) so that people could point you to R equivalents ...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the missing data view on CRAN:  [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html)

A popular R package for imputation (which is the name of this general area of research) is `mice`:  [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html)

Comment: I affirm that mice is one of the most popular packages to do what OP is asking. Here's a simple tutorial that shows how to impute missing values with mice: https://appsilon.com/imputation-in-r/.